# How to change navigate URL site logo to some different website ex: "www.google.com"?

Tags: sharepoint-online, branding

I want redirect user to different site (in other domain) on click on site logo. I'm using design manager to create master page and added navigate URL. But it is taking current site URL. any workarounds ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the relevant master page in Master Page Gallery through site settings->Master Pages and Page Layouts.

Edit the master page and replace the code below:

```
        <SharePoint:SPSimpleSiteLink CssClass="ms-siteicon-a" runat="server" id="onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic" >
            <SharePoint:SiteLogoImage CssClass="ms-siteicon-img" name="onetidHeadbnnr0" id="onetidHeadbnnr2" LogoImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/siteIcon.png?rev=42" runat="server"/>
        </SharePoint:SPSimpleSiteLink>
```

to

```
        <SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="http://www.google.com"  id="onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic">
            <SharePoint:SiteLogoImage CssClass="ms-siteicon-img" name="onetidHeadbnnr0" id="onetidHeadbnnr2" LogoImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/siteIcon.png?rev=42" runat="server"/>
        </SharePoint:SPLinkButton>
```

change the "NavigationUrl" value with your url.

Then save the file and upload to Master Page Gallery, and publish this master page. Finally, go to site settings->Look and Feel->Master page, change the site master page which you upload before.

Comment: I tried the above code it is not working, it is taking default value